# How to extract ONLY time from strptime()?

Tags: r, time, strptime

Part of the data looks like:

```
head(my_data[,c(1,2)], 3)
       Date Time 
1 16/12/2006 17:24:00 
2 16/12/2006 17:25:00 
3 16/12/2006 17:26:00
```

By the way, `str() $Date, $Time` are all chr now.

I want to keep them in two cols with correct format, so I use

```
x <- as.Date(my_data$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

to get the 1st col in date format :

```
x[1:5]
[1] "2006-12-16" "2006-12-16" "2006-12-16" "2006-12-16" "2006-12-16"
```

But in the 2nd col, when I'm trying to use

```
y <- strptime(my_data$Time, "%H:%M:%S")
```

The output automatically add default date and timezone of my computer.

```
y[1:4]
[1] "2017-01-10 17:24:00 CST" "2017-01-10 17:25:00 CST" 
[2] "2017-01-10 17:26:00 CST" "2017-01-10 17:27:00 CST"
```

What should I do if I just want to keep the time, without date and timezone?
Is `sub()` with some regular expression the only way to achieve this?

Comment: If you want to have a pure time object, you need a package that defines such a class. You could use package `chron`. However, I would suggest to combine date and time into a `POSIXct` object. There are nuisances such as leap years and leap seconds that need to be taken into account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sub` to extract the 'time' component

```
sub(".*\\s+", "",  y)
#[1] "17:24:00" "17:25:00" "17:26:00"
```

---

and if we want a `time` class, use the `times` from `chron`

```
library(chron)
times(my_data$Time)
#[1] 17:24:00 17:25:00 17:26:00
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think that's what I want to get. the `chron` package.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `format` to extract the time component

```
format(strptime(y, "%H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S")
```

---

Another alternative with `lubridate` package

```
library(lubridate)
hms(my_data$Time)
```

Comment: With `format` I can get only time listed, with `str()` get `chr`. But `format()` is very helpful for some other part of my code. Thanks!

Comment: @hepeng Try the `hms` function from `lubridate`.

Comment: `hms(date())` doesn't work! I think this suggestion is wrong altogether!

Comment: @ThejKiran works for me when I have `x <- c("17:24:00","17:25:00","17:26:00")` and then I do `lubridate::hms(x)`.